# How have a transition duration on a container which contain the element animate

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think I don't understand how work the transition-duration.

Here is the page:

```js
const li = document.querySelectorAll("li")

li.forEach((element)=>{
  element.addEventListener("mouseover",()=>{
    const p = element.querySelector("p");
    p.style.opacity = "1";
    p.style.height = "auto";
    p.style.width = "auto";
  })
  element.addEventListener("mouseout",()=>{
    const p = element.querySelector("p");
    p.style.opacity = "0"
    p.style.height = "0";
    p.style.width = "0";
  })
})
```

```css
li{
    overflow: hidden;

    background: #141516;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 46px;

    font-size: 36px;
    margin-bottom : auto;
    color: #eee;
}

li img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;

    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;

    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

li p{
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
      <img src="ressources/logo1.svg" alt="logo1">
      <p>text <span>text in span</span></p>
   </li>
   <li>  
      <img src="ressources/logo2.svg" alt="logo2">
      <p>text<span>text in span</span></p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My objective is to hide the text in the list (with display : none or with height = 0 + width = 0 + opacity = 0) and reveal the text when my mouse is over the list.

Well, this work ! Now I want to add a transition duration to the li element to have a smooth deformation of this element when the height and the width of the text change. But this didn't work !
Someone knows how can I add a transition duration to the li element ?

Thank you !

Comment: @SijilSasidharan 
No that didn't work. The transition work on the opacity, but not on the width and the height so the deformation of the <li> is instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

```css
li p { transition: width 2s, height 2s, opacity: 2s; }
```

or

```css
li p { transition: all 2s; }
```

I think this will work.

Instead of this you can use css `hover` I think?

```css
li p {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: all 2s;
}

li:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```